# Style Lint : Max Specificity Selector with Regex

Tags: css, regex, stylelint

I have a problem with Style Lint. I have set the selector-max-specificity at 0,2,0 with some ignored rules : `ignoreSelectors: [":focus", ":hover", etc..]`

Now, I want to ignore the `:not(.myClass)` selector but this doesn't work :(

For example i have my class with this name : `.track a:not(.track-visual)`

I have tried with regex selector `"/:not\\(.*\\)/"` or even with `"/.*:not\\(.*\\)/"`

But no chance :'(

If you have a solution, i'm interested :)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that here we would be wishing to capture those with `:not`, which in that event, we would be starting with a simple expression such as:

```
.+?:not\(.+?\)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tspTLe/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, i have tested your solution, but this is not working :'(
I don't understand why, because for example this is work well if i want to ignore selector attributes : `/\[.*\]/`

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this can be done. The [latest code for the rule](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/lib/rules/selector-max-specificity/index.js) includes the following:

```
const ownSpecificity =
    ownValue === ':not' || ownValue === ':matches'
        ? // :not and :matches don't add specificity themselves, but their children do
          zeroSpecificity()
        : simpleSpecificity(ownValue);
```

As per the comment, this is not including the `:not` itself as something that would add specificity but is including its children, which is what the regex would be checking.